# C++ - Топологическая сортировка на С++

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c++

Приведите пример топологической сортировки на С++.

Answer (score 4):

Если бы вы зашли в гугл, то сразу бы нашли:
http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/vis/graph-general/topological-sort-2007/algorithm или
http://acm.mipt.ru/twiki/bin/view/Algorithms/TopologicalSort
и так далее

Comment: Находил их, и еще пару тройку других. Но у меня, возможно конечно руки не из того места ростут, ни одна из программ не работает, всегда есть ошибки. Имея только процедуру, не могу дописать отсаток программы. В чувствах отчаяния написал на форум. Но, в любом случае, спасибо, что потратили на меня свое время!

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам на С, профессиональная реализация `tsort` из ядра BSD:

https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/tsort/tsort.c?view=markup

Что характерно она там действительно [часто находит применение для сортировки графов-зависимостей объектных файлов](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tsort-background.html) перед линковкой.

Comment: Не посмотрел на дату, бот поднимающий старые вопросы обманул меня.

Answer (score 1):

Когда у Вас возникают вопросы (относительно алгоритмов), Вы можете поискать ответы тут:

[http://informatics.mccme.ru/](http://informatics.mccme.ru),

e-maxx,

algolist

Кроме того, можно зайти на topCoder или codeforces, где часто предлагаются задачи на различные темы. Здесь можно найти исходники участников, которые решали эти задачи. Здесь с вероятностью 100% можно найти и топ-сорт.

P.s. Это на будущее. Конкретно на Ваш вопрос ответили. Если у Вас не работает код, то Вы могли бы привести пример ошибки, которую выдаёт компилятор.